# How to export large report to text file in SAP

Tags: printer, lpr, sap

**Goal**

Save a report from SAP to a file (that was produced by background job) (which runs for about 5 days before finishing)

**1. option 1 [has issue]: via Generic Printer Driver**

I have installed the Windows Generic/Text Only Printer Driver (under Windows 7).

The problem is that all lines are cut off at 167 characters: so any output after that column is not at all in the output (so not even wrapped) e.g. month 1 to 12 is visible, month 13 to 20 are not in the file. (it is however correct in the SAP preview window) (so it is not SAP).

**1.1 Test from notepad++**

When I create a file in notepad++ and type lines with the last character on position 204, then press print (printer on a3 and landscape), it still produces an output test.txt file that wraps every line at positions between 157-161, that is undesirable, I don't want any wrapping.

**1.2 How to have columns of 255 characters?**

Anyone has any experience OR has another option e.g. another printer driver that dumps to xx.txt and that has " really wide pages " so will not either cut off or wrap at a certain position?

**1.3 What I have tried**

Playing a lot with the printer properties of the generic printer driver: changing it to different formats etc... nothing seems to work. So either I solve this problem or return to previous attempts:

**2. option 2 via Spool>Looking glass>save as file  [has issue]**

This option (e.g. as described here: http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6750941) only outputs me the current content of the preview NOT all 38.269 pages which are in the testjob (have much larger ones). So this does not work for me.

***3. option 3 via Spool > menu spool > download to text  [has issue]***

The problem is that the output is that large that during the "download is running" a time-out occurs and Im left with half a file. It also seems to be incredibly slow as if it is running the job again.

Comment: Can't you cut the variant into smaller parts? That might even speed up processing.

Comment: I think that is the only option with #3, well... since im not always awake that will take me some extra week to check the jobs i think.